# Make flask app visible outside my own network on ubuntu

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspberry-pi4, raspberry-pi-pico

so im developing my own flask APP and I want to make it be visible to everyone outside my network since by setting host to "0.0.0.0" my website can only be accessed on every device in my network but not with people that is out of my network, Is there any way to make my flask app visible to everyone outside my network being hosted on a linux ubuntu device? (raspberry pi4)

Comment: Your router should have an option to set up port forwarding to have your router forward connections made to that port to your RPi's local IP. You should be aware of the security implications of opening up a port on your router to the world before you set this up. Needless to say, those not on your network have to connect using your public IP, which may or may not be static, depending on your ISP and subscription.

Comment: Have a read here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/70008814/2836621